# loading pre-trained vgg-16 on tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, vgg-net

I am trying to load a pre-trained vgg-16 network using tensorflow r1.1. The network is provided in 3 files:

- saved_model.pb
- variables/variables.index
- variables/variables.data-00000-of-00001

After initializing the variables `sess` as `tf.Session()`

I use the following script to load the network and extract some specific layers:

```
vgg_path='./'
model_filename = os.path.join(vgg_path, "saved_model.pb")
export_dir = os.path.join(vgg_path, "variables/")

with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
    data = compat.as_bytes(f.read())
    sm = saved_model_pb2.SavedModel()
    sm.ParseFromString(data)
    image_input, l7, l4, l3 = tf.import_graph_def(sm.meta_graphs[0].graph_def, 
            name='',return_elements=["image_input:0", "layer7_out:0",
            "layer4_out:0", "layer3_out:0"])

tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, image_input)
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, l7)
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, l4)
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, l3)

saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
print("load data")
saver.restore(sess, export_dir)
```

The script terminates with the following error when initializing the variable `saver`:

> TypeError: Variable to save is not a Variable: Tensor("image_input:0",
>   shape=(?, ?, ?, 3), dtype=float32)

How can I fix my script and have restore the pre-trained vgg network?

Comment: You could try the saved_model.loader https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/loader

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked for me! If you make it an answer I will accept it and put as a note my code solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model), you can use [tf.saved_model.loader](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/loader) for loading it:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["some_tag"], model_dir)
```